# how to push notification to android and ios platform at a hybird application which is using onsen-ui

Tags: push-notification, onsen-ui, monaca

I want to push notification to ios and android platform, my application is using onsen-ui and angularjs, my application backend is using PHP language.
At monaca, I use the MonacaPushNotifications plugin it works well, but according to my needs，I need to push different notifications to different users.
Then, I try workerman, but it just can push notification at web environment.

Anybody knows how to do it?Or is there has any other plugins can do it?It is better to push a notification in the backend depending on the data.

Thanks a lot

Comment: How do you use to send push notifications with monaca if you use your own backend? If you use monaca in your backend you can filter the http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/en/reference/monaca_api/cloud_management/push/, but otherwise you need to somehow connect your userid's in the backend with a specific device and then send them.

Comment: can you also add which php framework you are using, otherwise its hard to answer!